# Laravel 5 using HTML package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i'm trying to use this link [http://laravelcollective.com](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.0/html#installation) to install HTML and Form helper on laravel 5, after install that with composer like with

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

and update composer i'm add this lines on `app.php` file:

```
'providers' => [
    /* -------- */
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
],

'aliases' => [
    /* -------- */
    'Form'      => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
    'Html'      => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
],
```

and use from Html on view like with :

```
{{!! HTML::image(Captcha::img(), 'Captcha image',array('id'=>'captcha')) !!}}
```

I get this error:

```
Class 'HTML' not found
```

Comment: Your alias is Html not HTML!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's case-sensitive.

You need to change it to something like:

```
Html::image(Captcha::img(), 'Captcha image',array('id'=>'captcha'))
```

Also, use double curly braces `{{ }}` if you want to escape your HTML. In this case, you probably want to use `{!! !!}`. I'm not sure why you are doing both.

Edit: As noted by @ceejayoz, you can change the alias if you want to. So, for example, if you change your alias in your `config/app.php` file to all caps like this:

```
'HTML'      => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

Then, you can do this (to reflect your alias):

```
{!! HTML::image(Captcha::img(), 'Captcha image',array('id'=>'captcha')) !!}
```

Comment: Good answer. I'd just note that you can also change the alias, if preferred.